# How to manage numbers with x.999999 decimal places

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm facing the next problem.
I am performing mathematical operations to calculate weights where I am using a function to return only 2 decimal places but sometimes the result is not as expected. Here is an example

I have a paper that weighs 49.8 and I want to subtract 1/4, that is 12.45 and do it 4 times but when I do this subtraction 49.8 - 12.45 the result gives me 37.34999999999999999999994 when in fact it should be 37.35 because if I do the whole process with my function the result would not be 0, it would be as follows

- 49.8 - 12.45 = 37.34
- 37.34 - 12.45 = 24.89
- 24.89 - 12.45 = 12.44
- And you can't 12.44 - 12.45

So that's the problem because 49.8/4 = 12.45 but the way I'm doing it is not possible

How can I solve this, a way where if the third decimal place of the number is 9 round it and return it with only 2 decimals otherwise use my function to return it with 2 decimals

My function:

```
function threeDecimals(num) {
  const multipliedNum = num * 100;
  const truncatedNum = Math.trunc(multipliedNum);
  const num3decimals = truncatedNum / 100;
  return num3decimals;
}
```

Comment: Why not just round all the numbers to 2 decimal places? 12.45 rounded to 2 decimal places is still 12.45.

Comment: I dont want to round it if is not 999999, example if the number is 18.567 I want it 18.56 not 18.57

Comment: You can instead round it at the 10th decimal place or something like that. `x = Number(x.toFixed(10))` - this should have enough precision for your purpose but be several orders of magnitudes above the rounding errors

Comment: I understand what you mean, but sometimes the result of the operation will have more than 3 decimals and will not be .9999 so I don't want that, I want to keep the 2 decimals without rounding and round only if the third decimal is 9. @CherryDT

Comment: But what you are saying is not logical, why would `12.34905` not be valid and become `12.35` while `12.34805` would stay? You _have_ to set a max. precision at some point, at a point that's before the area of rounding errors, no?

Comment: What I mean is that when the number is 12.3499999..., it approximates 12.35 but if it is 12.34805 it is not rounded but just 12.34 because I am making real life cuts that are accurate and I don't need approximations, just in case .9999999999999999 is actually 1

Comment: But around 15 decimals you will start to get floating point errors so you have to round your number below that, for example 10 or 12

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers have this property by design. If you need to have base-10 precision, it's not enough to add a few decimals and round, because errors can still slip in in higher precisions.

You will need to use a third party library that guarantees base10 accuracy for the examples you gave.

Note that nothing will give you accuracy for every type of operation. Even `Decimal.js` will round `1/3` and not have a perfect representation, just like floating point numbers give seemingly 'incorrect' outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact calculations, operate on smaller units (milligrams instead of grams), so that intermediate values are always integers:

```js
weight = 49800
f = (weight / 4) | 0


weight -= f
weight -= f
weight -= f

result = weight / 1000

console.log(result)
```